# Exact sequence with flat module tensored by module stays exact

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, flatness

The following theorem is given in Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Proposition 1.2.6:

Let $A$ be a ring. Let $0\to M^\prime\to M\to M^{\prime\prime}\to 0$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules. Let us suppose that $M^{\prime\prime}$ is flat. Then the sequence $0\to M^\prime \otimes N\to M\otimes N\to M^{\prime\prime} \otimes N\to 0$ is also exact for any $A$-module $N$.

Liu gives a proof on page 9. I have problems to understand the proof. The mistake is easy to fix, Proposition 2.12 should be 1.12. But what does the "Let us write $N$ as the quotient of a free $A$-module $L$ by a submodule $K$" means? Is it $N=L/K$? And how one can do the diagram chasing part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a surjective homomorphism of $A$-modules $L\to N$ and denote its kernel by $K$. Then, by the fundamental isomorphism theorem we have $N\simeq L/K$.

The diagram chasing isn't that hard: let $x\in M\otimes N$ which is sent to $0$; since $\beta$ is surjective there is $y\in M'\otimes L$ such that $x=\beta(y)$. Now let $f=(M\otimes L\to M\otimes N)$, and $g=(M'\otimes L\to M\otimes L)$. From the commutativity of the diagram we have $(f\circ g)(y)=0$, so $g(y)\in\ker f$. But $\ker f=\operatorname{im}h$, where $h=(M\otimes K\to M\otimes L)$, so $g(y)=h(z)$, $z\in M\otimes K$. Let $u=(M\otimes L\to M''\otimes L)$ and $v=(M\otimes K\to M''\otimes K)$. We have $(\alpha\circ v)(z)=(u\circ h)(z)=u(h(z))=u(g(y))=0$ since $\operatorname{im}g=\ker u$. So, $\alpha(v(z))=0$ and since $\alpha$ is injective we get $v(z)=0$, that is, $z\in\ker v$. Then there is $z'\in M'\otimes K$ such that $z=w(z')$, where $w=(M'\otimes K\to M\otimes K)$. We have $(h\circ w)(z')=h(w(z'))=h(z)=g(y)$. On the other side, $h\circ w=g\circ h'$, where $h'=(M'\otimes K\to M'\otimes L)$, so $g(y)=g(h'(z'))$ and since $g$ is injective we get $y=h'(z')$. The final step is to recall that $x=\beta(y)=(\beta\circ h')(z')=0$ for $\operatorname{im}h'=\ker\beta$.

**Remark.** Instead of the above diagram chasing you can use the [Snake lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma#Statement) (which is the right tool for such things). All your data fit well into the lemma, the last kernel is $0$ (as being $\ker\alpha$), while the first two cokernels are $M'\otimes N$, respectively $M\otimes N$ (because the vertical maps are surjective).

Answer (score 8):

Consider the diagram of the proof:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} @. M'\otimes K @>f>> M\otimes K @>g>> M''\otimes K \\
@. @VVhV @VViV @VV{\alpha}V \\
0 @>>> M'\otimes L @>j>> M\otimes L @>k>> M''\otimes L \\
@. @VV{\beta}V @VVlV \\
{} @. M'\otimes N @>m>> M\otimes N \\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
{} @. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}
$$

Let $x\in\ker m$; then $x=\beta(y)$ and $lj(y)=0$, so $j(y)=i(z)$.

Thus $\alpha g(z)=ki(z)=kj(y)=0$, so $g(z)=0$ and therefore $z=f(u)$.

Since $jh(u)=if(u)=i(z)=j(y)$, we have $y-h(u)\in\ker j=\{0\}$, so $y=h(u)$ and finally $x=\beta(y)=\beta h(u)=0$.

Comment: @egreg Umm. I don't see where you defined $y$. Why do $x=\beta (y)$ makes sense? Do you mean that there is an $y\in M'\otimes L$ such that $x=\beta(y)$?

Comment: @user2219896 The map $\beta$ is surjective because the tensor product is right exact.

Answer (score 1):

$$0=\mathrm{Tor}^1(M^{\prime\prime},N)\to  M^\prime \otimes N\to M\otimes N\to M^{\prime\prime} \otimes N\to 0$$
$0=\mathrm{Tor}^1(M^{\prime\prime},N)$, since $M^{\prime\prime}$ is flat.